# Using Realm inside framework

Tags: ios, realm

I can not use Realm within my framework as a framework because apple rejects nested frameworks.
However maybe there is no problem in using Realm as a pod depedence within my framework. Or is there a problem?
How does objective C be a single namespace I will not have collisions?

In my framework I want to capture GPS coordinates.
What is the benefit of using Realm for this versus file system?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that the iOS App Store doesn't allow nested dynamic frameworks. The suggested solution is to place frameworks at the same directory level in your app bundle.

The benefits of using Realm are well documented on the official website: https://realm.io

Comment: You don't answer all my questions. And about pods inside my frameworks they are allowed?

Comment: CocoaPods with the `use_frameworks!` directive builds all pods as their own unique dynamic framework, which are all copied into the host app at the same directory level of the app bundle. This is exactly what I explained in my answer, CocoaPods just happens to automate this.

Comment: But I don't understand. If I transform my framework in workspace with pods it will include libPods.a in my Linked Frameworks of my Framework and that will be considered a nested framework.

Comment: If you have libPods.a, that's because you're not using CocoaPods's `use_frameworks!` directive, but instead instructing CocoaPods to generate a single static library containing all your pods for that platform. This is then _statically_ linked into your main app binary, leading to a single binary. This is in contrast to dynamic libraries which are shipped as distinct executables from your main app binary.