# Swift umbrella framework

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I'm using Realm with cocoapods inside a framework I've created.

When I tried to import my framework to my app, the app shows following error:

> Realm dependency doesn't found.

When I import Realm directly in my app, the error disappear.

How can I import my framework to my app without importing Realm directly into the app?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43477988/using-realm-inside-framework ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Realm inside framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43477988/using-realm-inside-framework)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30772004/ios-8-framework-with-nested-embedded-framework